# Is my MainActivity File corrupt after PC failure?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was using Android Studio, latest release yesterday when my PC decided to just turn off(Turns out PSU's dont last forever). I took the HDD out until I can find a replacement PSU and put it into another PC, upon opening my project I can open the MainAcivity anymore with Android Studio. I opened the Java file with a text editor and it comes up with about 8000 lines of 0's.

Does anyone know how to fix this as I put alot of work and time into that file?

[image: What Android Studio Displays]

Comment: This is the reason we should make backups. Your file is corrupted now and you should recreate it from the start. You can try decoding your old apk files and using that as base, but you properly won't be able to get it back. If you were using a revision history system like git, you can try hard resetting to the point of your latest release.

Comment: Unfortunately I think the crash corrupted your file. Always keep a backup of your work or use a Version Control.

Comment: Thanks @Ferrybig , ashame will try decoding the APK, a expensive lesson lol

Comment: Decompiling apk's can be super easy, try out an online decompiler: [Online APK Decompiler](http://www.decompileandroid.com/) I use it a lot. I would be wary about uploading your project, hopefully it's not near finished so the person behind the site can't just steal your app. I'm paranoid about that stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is corrupted, the sector of the disk where the file is stored is effectively damaged / unallocated because the file was being held in the disk cache / currently written.

### Resetting the file from version control

If you use a version control mechanism such as [git](/questions/tagged/git), [mercurial](/questions/tagged/mercurial) or [cvs](/questions/tagged/cvs), you can try check-out the file from the system from the moment of your latest successful check-in. If that fails you can try cloning/checkout out the online version of your repository and see if that is the correct version to.

### Recovering the file from backups

Every person SHOULD have a proper backup system, making backups is relatively easy to do, and even a [git](/questions/tagged/git) repository stored on multiple computers can already be a good backup.

Even [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/) has made [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33346/recovering-a-lost-website-with-no-backup) mistake in the past. (yes, he is user 1)

### Recovering the file using disk checking applications

Sometimes, you may have more luck using `chkdsk` on Windows or `fsck` on Linux.

This may happen because you worked on the file, and the file system decided to move the file to another sector for various reasons. Then, while it was moving the file, the hard disk crashed. This left the file pointer referring to the new location, while the file is still safe at the old location.

On Linux and Mac, files recovered by this technique are stored in directory `/lost+found`, while on Windows, this directory is called "/Found" located in the affected hard drive.

### Decompiling your old application

Sometimes, the above techniques are delivering anything resembling your original code. In this case we need to use our must ugly method, decompiling.

There are various java and android decompilers you can use, these can be easily found on google by searching for "java decompiler". I am not going to name them here to prevent this answer from becoming opinium based on what decompiler is the best.